# Multiplication not explicitly definable in $\mathfrak{M}=\langle R, < , + \rangle$

Tags: proof-writing, model-theory

Prove that Multiplication is not explicitly definable in $\mathfrak{M}=\langle R, < , + \rangle$.

I started with $F(x)=2x$ and I basically need to show it is an automorphism of $\mathfrak{M}$

And then I think it would be easiest to assume it is explicitly definable and try to get a contradiction by using the automorphism theorem. But I do not know how to proceed and show the automorphism.

Comment: @bof Sorry, didn't make myself very clear. I know how to show it meets the requirements of an automorphism but I don't know how to go on from there, in other words; how to get a contradiction.

Comment: If multiplication were definable, then $1$ would be definable too, right? And if $1$ were definable, then $1$ would have to be fixed by every automorphism, right? Where's the snag? By the way, what theorem is it that you refer to as "the automorphism theorem"?

Comment: @bof I was referring to Hurwitz's automorphisms theorem.

Comment: and 1 would not be definable because it would not preserve the properties.

Comment: $1$ is certainly definable it you assume that multiplication is definable: $$x=1\iff\forall y\ xy=y.$$

Comment: Oh if it were definable yes, ohhhh I see!! Okay I will work on it.